# Filter week from list of dates

Tags: c#, .net

I have a list of dates, how can I select a week from it?

**Suppose this is the list of dates:**

```
02/11/2012
11/25/2012
04/08/2012
12/03/2012
04/13/2012
04/11/2012
12/12/2012
01/25/2012
04/10/2012
04/12/2012
04/09/2012
05/23/2012
10/05/2012
01/25/2012
04/14/2012
```

**The extracted week should be like this:**

```
04/08/2012
04/09/2012
04/10/2012
04/11/2012
04/12/2012
04/13/2012
04/14/2012
```

**Edit:**

I have a table in the DB that contains dates, I need when I fetch all records, to filter the data according to these dates and view them in weeks.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 2):

If I understood right you want to group dates from your list in a way, that dates from the same week would be in the same group. I think it should be done this way:

```
var dates = (..) // your list of dates

var dtf = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo;

var groupedDates = dates.GroupBy(d => dtf.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(d, dtf.CalendarWeekRule, dtf.FirstDayOfWeek));
```

After that you'll be able to select dates from chosen week:

```
var myWeekDates = groupedDates.SingleOrDefault(g => g.Key == myWeekNr);
```

or simply iterate through all groups:

```
foreach(var g in groupedDates)
{
    // (...)
    // g.Key is #nr of the week
    // g is IEnumerable<DateTime> with dates within that week
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you selecting these records from the database?

Maybe you can handle it in SQL:

```
SELECT DATEPART(WK, date_column) FROM table;
```

It returns the week number of the date so you can either get the first day or last day of that week.